# How to backup Salesforce to Box?

Tags: backup

I have a box.com account and is there a way for me to backup salesforce to box? How can I just download and pull all files in salesforce as export and automatically save it into box?

Comment: why do you want to backup from one cloud to another cloud environment ?

Comment: I have an automatic data export setup in salesforce and I need these to be securely backed-up in my box account.

Comment: Are we talking about data or metadata(configuration) here ? Just your personal  files or the whole org's ? Please understand that this question is very  broad which makes it hard to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

I use cloudHQ. They sync all my Salesforce documents, files, reports, and records to Box- and I don't even really need to schedule anything since it's always being updated in real time. 
Another helpful feature is that I can also upload anything into my Box folder, which then gets synched out to my Salesforce notes, documents, and chatter files. 
It's pretty inexpensive and is thus far the most reliable sync I've found to date.

Disclaimer: I'm associated with the company.

Comment: I think you should add some disclosure here. Given your avatar, I suspect you're more than just a happy CloudHQ user...

Comment: @metadaddy: Noone can backup Salesforce like cloudHQ. Simply put, it goes beyond nice GUIs and actually delivers a reliable service that works. Try it and see for yourself: https://www.cloudhq.net/dropbox/sync/box/salesforce

Answer (score 1):

You can use services like Zapier to automate some things between Salesforce and Box.  But it will be most straight forward to just download the scheduled export and to you box sync folder or something if you really wanted to back it up to Box.